# Should columns supporting a beam be fastened to the floor?

Tags: beam, building

[image]I am trying to take down a load bearing wall and have had an engineer draw plans and advise I use a steel beam and columns to support the floor above. 
Do I need something to secure the columns to the floor so they do not move or can the rest direct into the concrete floor?
I live in Scotland which tends to have different laws than the rest of the UK.

columns 90 x 6.3 SHS
beam 178 x 102 x 19 UB

The beam will have JJI joists resting on it. I have a 3 floor terraced house and the work is being carried out on the ground floor.

Comment: Usually steel posts have plates welded to the ends with bolt holes punched in them. We'd need more detail about your columns to answer, though.

Comment: I’m trying to load image of plans but struggling on phone. Will switch to laptop

Comment: Not the plans so much, but the metal bits.

Comment: When you say, “can they rest direct into the concrete floor” I presume they have an end cap so the column can develop the necessary bearing on/in the concrete.

Comment: @Lee Sam I thought the engineer would have clarified these details and I’m struggling to get a quote for the materials from local steel fabricators.

Comment: yes, you want them attached, as a home inspector explained to me, in case of earthquake, kids, or accidentally bumping into one with your arms loaded. Strictly speaking, that doesn't provide support, but it provides robustness.

Comment: Don’t get many earthquakes in Scotland, unless they are fraking nearby?!?

Comment: I'd go back to the engineer.  You may need to crack concrete and dig a new footing.  When I did a similar thing, I needed to dig down 18" add some rebar, and re-pour concrete.

Comment: Second @Chris Cudmore’s suggestion. The engineer really needs to specify the footing required for the posts.

Comment: I thought the engineer should be providing more information. I hope it’s not a case of ‘he’s paid so ignore him’!

Answer (score 1):

Either the plate with bolt holes as suggested.

Or you could bolt some blocks to the floor on each side of the beam to stop it moving - especially if it does not have a plate already.

But some method of stopping it moving too easily is sensible - "just in case"...

Comment: If blocks were used, you’d want them on all 4 sides of the column to keep it from moving in both directions.

Comment: @LeeSam each side... means all four, not any two of choice...

Comment: Exactly. Regardless of local code, failure to secure posts at either end is a ReallyBadIdea(TM)